# scroll to element according to class, when another element is clicked

Tags: javascript

I would like to have the page scroll into an element with class xxxx when any element with class yyyy is clicked.
I wrote this down but it does not work. Any help? I am sure I am doing something wrong but I don't know what.

```
var my_event = document.getElementsByClassName('yyyy');
my_event.onclick = function zb_scroll_function() {
const activity = document.getElementsByClassName('xxxx');
activity.scrollIntoView();};
```

On a site that I have no access over the DOM layout, I want to scroll to another area of the site when a link with a specific class is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Getting elements by class name by `getElementsByClassName` you receiving `HTMLCollection` of elements, no single element.

but `scrollIntoView` is defined on single element, not a collection.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

You can try:

```
const activity = document.querySelector('.xxxx');
```

To better understand context you should read also:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

and

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection